# Different modes of convergence of Random variables in layman's language

Tags: probability, statistics

I am looking for the explanation, significance and difference between different convergence modes of random variables in simple terms.

I read and reread the concepts but I don't think I got them correctly.
And equations are not giving me enough intuition so that I can explain them to someone else. I am looking for some analogies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could state the impressions that you have so that we can correct them.

Comment: That said, I can do this much. Almost sure convergence is the thing that we can easily measure: you get a sequence of numbers randomly obtained and that sequence of numbers converges to another random number. Convergence in distribution is not really a probabilistic concept *per se*: you have a sequence of distributions (which needn't be on the same probability space!) whose CDFs converge to another CDF.

Comment: Convergence in probability says that the probability of deviations between $X_n$ and $X$ of size larger than any fixed tolerance goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. As for convergence in $L^p$ (including the important special case of $L^2$), I don't really have a good intuition for it.

Comment: sure. I will try to explain what I understood correctly or incorrectly :).
This is my way of understanding things. Sorry for my inappropriate analogies. Almost sure convergence implies that there will be a point in the sequence of rv's that rv's start going towards a certain value.
Analogy: no matter how ever many years any one lives, ultimately every one has to die THE POINT of no return. Convergence in mean for me is same as Almost sure convergence. 
Though I understand that there is a lot of difference, I cannot find any analogy which means this I didnt understand clearly.

Comment: Convergence in probability implies that as the sequence of rv's goes to infinity rv's converges to a value, still there is a chance of odd rv going away.
Analogy: In married man's life, as the marital life goes on as the understanding between partners increases, there is high possibility that man goes to his house than his gf's house. But there is still a possibility that he may go to his gf's house once in a while.

Comment: Convergence in distribution helps in only understanding stats, like finding out probabilities, nothing else except that.
Analogy: Meeting a person in shopping mall who is similar in shape as one's friend and asking him to try and see how one's choice of shirt fits him.

Comment: Your analogy for almost sure convergence makes it sound like the limit is not random, but the limit is indeed random. Your comparison for convergence in mean is just wrong; neither of these implies the other. I'm not really sure about whether either of your other analogies mean very much, except that it is definitely correct that convergence in distribution only describes the distributions themselves, not comparing particular values of two random variables (which is relevant to all the other convergence types that we've discussed here).

Comment: @Ian yeah I know I didn't understand convergence of mean or for that matter I am not sure about other ones also. That is the reason i am asking for analogies and intuition so that I can correct my self